# Qual o "real" significado da palavra-chave 'extends' em Java?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, terminologia, herança

Antes de mais nada, eu sei como se usa e funciona a palavra-chave `extends`, a minha real dúvida está no significado dessa palavra, mais precisamente por que `extends` e não `inherit` ou algo do tipo? A única coisa que vem a minha mente com essa palavra é que o escopo da subclasse atual se "estende" ao da superclasse, e mesmo assim, por que isso?

Comment: Quem criou a linguagem decidiu assim ? (só um pitaco, não sei realmente)

Comment: Eu sei que tem algum significado além, assim como o significado de classes (que pouca gente sabe), mas não consigo me lembrar

Comment: No [glossário da Oracle][1]:**extends-**
O Termo é usado em uma declaração de classe para especificar a superclasse.
Em uma declaração de interface é utilizado pra especificar uma ou mais superinterfaces. 
A classe X estende a classe Y para adicionar funcionalidade, seja por incluir campos ou métodos à classe Y ou sobrescrevendo métodos da classe Y. Uma interface Z estende uma ou mais interfaces adicionando métodos .A classe X é considerada uma subclasse da classe Y. A interface Z é considerada uma subinterface das interfaces que ela se estende.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essas coisas você nunca consegue afirmar com certeza a não ser que tenha um documento que diga porque foi feita esta escolha, o que eu desconheço que exista.

O mais provável por essa escolha é que a semântica mais correta é estender aquela classe, que é diferente de implementar uma interface e que ambas estão fazendo uma herança, portanto se usasse `inherits` ela definiria mal o que é aquilo, que até é uma herança, mas tem outra coisa que é herança também (a taxonomia permite ter mais de um nome para algo que possui níveis diferentes de observação), então fazia mais sentido assim. Pelo menos a escolha tem uma lógica.

Uma interface estende outra interface. Curiosamente em versões novas é possível estender uma interface, ainda que o termo continua igual, não faria sentido em alguns casos usar uma palavra e e outros usar outro termo, é melhor aceitar que não é sempre o melhor termo, linguagens não são línguas. Nem sempre é fácil fazer o correto.

Algumas pessoas criticam C# que usa `:` para tudo, mas pelo menos não é uma palavra que dá um significado mais específico.

Comment: Achei que merecia uma menção ao `extends` para interface. Apesar de ser o mesmo conjunto de caracteres, a semântica, para mim, é bem distinta

Comment: Você acha? Porque ela realmente estende de alguma forma a outra. Não é exatamente a mesma coisa.